# Sending email with Go/TLS results in "remote error: handshake failure" response

Tags: email, ssl, go

We're using the Go smtp.SendMail() function to send email. If we disable that function from using TLS, we have no problems sending email to kaser.com. With using TLS, we get the following error: `remote error: handshake failure`.

If I run `openssl s_client -connect kaser.com:25 -starttls smtp`, I get the following:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = COMODO SSL Wildcard, CN = *.inmotionhosting.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=COMODO SSL Wildcard/CN=*.inmotionhosting.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=COMODO SSL Wildcard/CN=*.inmotionhosting.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4861 bytes and written 596 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: F532F400F99290364AECE777619E466E7C3C3086D23F77F694AEA7F86DB4A2A7
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: BF3551E6A77A02A7AA8F0273B1478D7C17AF6404D176974F55CDC4287671FAC71C7E454224001BE15C57BE6254CE5094
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1455730440
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 HELP
quit
```

Any ideas why it doesn't like Go's TLS?

Comment: That openssl session is connected with `RC4-SHA`. RC4 is weak, and is now officially prohibited in the TLS spec. If the server offers nothing else, then the default Go tls config can't connect.

Comment: Is there any way to add `RC4-SHA` support? The user has no problems receiving email from other services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain that the server only accepts insecure cipher suites and can't be updated, go does have some RC4 ciphers included, but disabled.

The `smtp.SendMail` convenience function doesn't have a way to change the `tls.Config`, but it's easy to take the body of that function and use the `smtp.Client` manually.

You can create a `tls.Config` with the CipherSuites you want, and pass it to `Client.StartTLS`

```
config := &tls.Config{
    ServerName:   serverName,
    CipherSuites: []uint16{tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA},
}

// c is an smtp.Client
if err = c.StartTLS(config); err != nil {
    return err
}
```